# coin is tossed and based on its outcome a number is shown

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Two integers are chosen from $(-\infty,\infty)$. A fair coin is tossed and its outcome is not revealed. If **Head** comes, the larger number is shown and if **Tail** comes, the smaller one is shown.

What is the probability of correctly guessing the number to be larger or smaller ?

P.S: The guess must be correct with probability strictly greater than $0.5$

Comment: Depends on what strategy you use. If you just guess randomly, it’s 50%. There exist other strategies which succeed with a probability of more than 50%.

Comment: Also depends on how you chose your two numbers right ?

Comment: It sounds as if you're looking for [the randomized solution to the two envelopes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_envelopes_problem#Randomized_solutions)?

Comment: Great. Thanks @joriki for pointing out.

Comment: Does that answer your question? Then I'd write it up as a short answer so you can mark the question as answered.

Comment: Yes it does. The solution is written there in the wikipedia article itself.

Comment: if you have a distribution from which X and Y are chosen, then let A be the random guess.  What you are looking for is $P(A = max(X,Y)/H) + P(A = min(X,Y)/T)$ which again is $\frac{1}{2} [P(A = max(X,Y)) + P(A = min(X,Y))]$.